# Deactivating jest warnings in a @vue/cli (vue-cli) project?

Tags: vuejs2, jestjs, suppress-warnings, vue-cli

I've set up a @vue/cli project and want to deactivate jest warnings and want to see errors only.

How and where can I do that?

Comment: Could you please share how the warning looks like to you?

Comment: Add a `setup.js` file and add `console.warn = jest.genMockFunction();` to the same. this should disable warning

Comment: @Lonely, did you get a chance to check it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3 days ago they published a flag `hideStyleWarn` in `2.4.0`.

You can add this to disable CSS warnings :

```
      // package.json
      {
        "jest": {
          "globals": {
            "vue-jest": {
              "hideStyleWarn": true
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

According to the [doc](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/cli.html#silent) you can also run jest in silent mode with `--silent` command option.

> All Jest command line options are also supported.

Check this for more [Vue Jest Doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest)

Comment: maybe try to use --silent param